# PHP: query with 2 arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to make a search using a query with 2 variables that are arrays:

```
$Text   = Isset($_POST['Text'])      ? $_POST['Text']       : $Text      = Null;
$Num    = Isset($_POST['Num'])      ? $_POST['Num']       : $Num      = Null;

foreach($Num as $vN){

$aSel = 'SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE eID = "'.$vN.'" AND zText = "HERE TO EXTRACT TEXT VALUES"';  

}
```

What is the solution to extract Text value and insert them in the query??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting to search for the same index in the `$Text` array as you are currently on in the `$Num` array?

Comment: Where is the text value going to go in your query? If both `$Text` and `$Num` are to be arrays, why not just use nested for loops?

Comment: the index is different, so I cannot use it as reference
@the_pete: I did not get your idea

Comment: So what logic specifies which element from `$Text` to use?

Comment: I want to get value per value, i.e: 
`$Text = array('text1', 'text2', 'text3');`
so I want to search for 3 of them

so my query will be something like:
`SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE eID = "32" AND zText = "Text1"';  
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE eID = "20" AND zText = "Text2"';
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE eID = "14" AND zText = "Text3"';`

Comment: And you want to do individual queries for each of those? Or you want to do one query and get results that match _all_ elements? Or you want to do one query and get results that match _any_ elements? You really need to clarify your question. It would be helpful if you gave sample table data as well as sample input and the expected output for that input based on the sample data.

Comment: I want to have it like the code above:
Query1
Query2
and so on

Comment: Help us help you. Providing sample table data, sample inputs, and related desired output is the easiest way for us to know exactly what you're trying to do. Since you did not provide the `$Num` array in your comment above, it is impossible to know where `32`, `20`, and `14` come from, and what their relation to the `$Text` array is (if any). Chances are, Nordenheim's answer is what you want, you just don't realize it.

Comment: I do have a form with to fields, Num and Text `<input type="text" name="Num[]">` and `<input type="hidden" name="Text[]">` so these will generate 2 arrays while we click on Send button, so the second page will get theses 2 variables as I posted above, now doing a foreach to extract values of Num is fine, how can I extract Text values inside the foreach of Num?